# Restrict ServiceAccount / Role to manage secrets in all clusters

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to restrict a `ServiceAccount`'s RBAC permissions to manage secrets in all namespaces:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: gitlab-secrets-manager
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  resourceNames:
  - gitlab-registry
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - create
  - update
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-service-account
  namespace: gitlab
secrets:
- name: gitlab-service-account-token-lllll
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-service-account-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: gitlab-secrets-manager
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: gitlab-service-account
  namespace: gitlab
```

So far, I've created the ServiceAccount and the related CRB, however, actions are failing:

```
secrets "gitlab-registry" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "shamil"
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Please can post your ServiceAccount and ClusterRoleBinding yaml outputs?

Comment: @bear Have you create a `clusterrolebinding` resource?

Comment: @Shudipta Sharma, I've posted the ClusterRoleBinding resource

Comment: @mWatney I've added them both

Comment: @bear Also ensure that you specified the correct ServiceAccount name in the field `.spec` of your podTemplateSpec.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma looks like that's correct

Comment: Can you double check what service account are you using? I can see in the error `"system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default"` and in your yaml file I can see `gitlab-service-account` ServiceAccount. Another thing is that in your `
ClusterRoleBinding` the `ServiceAccount` namespace is `default` and it should be `gitlab`.

Comment: @mWatney It should be `gitlab-service-account`. though I can't see why it's `gitlab`. I've corrected the namespace

Comment: What are you running to get this error message? kubectl? Using API? Probably you are doing it using a wrong ServiceAccount. I've reproduced your scenario and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following steps:

- At first, you need to insure that your serviceaccount named `gitlab-service-account` in  `gitlab` namespace exists in the cluster.
- Then you will create a `ClusterRole` as you have given:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: gitlab-secrets-manager
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - secrets
    resourceNames:
      - gitlab-registry
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - update
```

- Then you will also create a `ClusterRoleBinding` to grant permission at the cluster level.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-secrets-manager-clusterrolebinding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-service-account    
    namespace: gitlab
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: gitlab-secrets-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```